Why does my Yubikey need to be unplugged/replugged once in a while?
My Yubikey is generally working fine on macOS:

It can always write an OTP as a keyboard
ykman always works
gpg --card-status works for a while after I plug the Yubikey

However, after a while when running on a USB hub, gpg --card-status stops working and shows the following error instead:
% gpg --card-status
gpg: selecting card failed: Operation not supported by device
gpg: OpenPGP card not available: Operation not supported by device

Unplugging and replugging the Yubikey solves the problem... for a while.
The Yubikey is plugged into my screen (which is plugged to the MacBook over USB-C). The exact same setup always works on Linux.
What could be causing this?
Could it be that macOS somehow does something with smart cards, which would interfere with the gpg-agent? I noticed that macOS regularly shows notifications that essentially say that "a smartcard was plugged" and "a smartcard was unplugged" (I would say every few minutes). This sounds like there may be something conflicting (maybe a macOS service trying to access the smartcard?).
